# Convert a string's character encoding from windows-1252 to utf-8

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had converted a Word Document(docx) to html, the converted html has windows-1252 as its character encoding. In .Net for this 1252 character encoding all the special characters are being displayed as '�'. This html is being displayed in a Rad Editor which displays correctly if the html is in Utf-8 format.

I had tried the following code but no vein

```
Encoding wind1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);  
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;  
byte[] wind1252Bytes = wind1252.GetBytes(strHtml);  
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(wind1252, utf8, wind1252Bytes);  
char[] utf8Chars = new char[utf8.GetCharCount(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length)];   
utf8.GetChars(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length, utf8Chars, 0);  
string utf8String = new string(utf8Chars);
```

Any suggestions on how to convert the html into UTF-8?

Comment: Depending on the type of project you have (e.g. .NetCore), you might also need to first install the Nuget package `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` and do a initialisation in the class constructor, with `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);`

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/SeppPenner/ae65fccdd81bce23cd8818ffe22589c1 for an example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually the problem lies here

```
byte[] wind1252Bytes = wind1252.GetBytes(strHtml);
```

We should not get the bytes from the html String. I tried the below code and it worked.

```
Encoding wind1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] wind1252Bytes = ReadFile(Server.MapPath(HtmlFile));
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(wind1252, utf8, wind1252Bytes);
string utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);


public static byte[] ReadFile(string filePath)      
    {      
        byte[] buffer;   
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  
        try
        {
            int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length    
            buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer     
            int count;                            // actual number of bytes read     
            int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read    

            // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)    
            while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
                sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
        }
        finally
        {
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: OK; i don't think i'm catching it - you are saying don't GetBytes from the .net string, but rather binary-read it directly from the filesystem. Why does this work? b/c the .net string is internally UTF-16?

Comment: i think he wants to say that system locale effects bytes so it never encode good so instead need to read real source to get real bytes and then convert.

Answer (score 26):

This should do it:

```
Encoding wind1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;  
byte[] wind1252Bytes = wind1252.GetBytes(strHtml);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(wind1252, utf8, wind1252Bytes);
string utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

How you are planning to use resulting html? The most appropriate way in my opinion to solve your problem would be add `meta` with encoding specification. Something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Encoding.Convert` method. Details are in the [Encoding.Convert method MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but I had tried that, don't know why its not working for me.