# Converting windows-1252 encoding to UTF-8 in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

In my Silverlight Application I am getting an XML File encoded with windows-1252.
Now my Problem it won't display correctly until the windows-1252 string is converted to a UTF8 string. 
In a normal C# enviornment that wouldn't be that big of a problem: There I could do something like this:

```
Encoding wind1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] wind1252Bytes = ReadFile(Server.MapPath(HtmlFile));
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(wind1252, utf8, wind1252Bytes);
string utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

([Convert a string's character encoding from windows-1252 to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568033/convert-a-strings-character-encoding-from-windows-1252-to-utf-8))

But silverlight doesn't support windows-1252 - it is unicode only.

PS 
I stumbled upon "Encoding for Silverlight" http://encoding4silverlight.codeplex.com/ - but it seems there is no support for windows-1252 there either?

**EDIT:**
I solved my problem on the "Server Side" - The actual problem is still open.

Answer (score 1):

`Encoding for Silverlight` is a third party encoding system but only supported all `DBCS (Double-Byte Character Set)` now. However, windows-1252 is `SBCS (Single-Byte Character Set)`.

But you can write a encoder/decoder for `Encoding for Silverlight`, I Think will be very easy.