# character encoding downloading webpage

Tags: c#, html, encoding, character-encoding

I've to download webpages to a text file and analyse the words.

They are in differents chatsets, iso-8859-1, windows-1252... I've tried several solutions from SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9841920/3865475) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568033/) and more but they hadn't work, I'm still reading m&# xED;nimo (without the space of course) where I should to read mínimo or M&e acute;xico

Someone can put me on the correct way? thanks!

```
public static string DownloadString(string address)
{
    string strWebPage = "";
    // create request
    System.Net.WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(address);
    // get response
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse objResponse;
    objResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
    // get correct charset and encoding from the server's header
    string Charset = objResponse.CharacterSet;
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(Charset);

    // read response into memory stream
    MemoryStream memoryStream;
    using (Stream responseStream = objResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int byteCount;
        do
        {
            byteCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
        } while (byteCount > 0);
    }

    // set stream position to beginning
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream, encoding);
    strWebPage = sr.ReadToEnd();

    // Check real charset meta-tag in HTML
    int CharsetStart = strWebPage.IndexOf("charset=");
    if (CharsetStart > 0)
    {
        CharsetStart += 8;
        int CharsetEnd = strWebPage.IndexOfAny(new[] { ' ', '\"', ';' }, CharsetStart);
        string RealCharset =
               strWebPage.Substring(CharsetStart, CharsetEnd - CharsetStart);

        // real charset meta-tag in HTML differs from supplied server header???
        if (RealCharset != Charset)
        {
            // get correct encoding
            Encoding CorrectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(RealCharset);

            // reset stream position to beginning
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // reread response stream with the correct encoding
            StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(memoryStream, CorrectEncoding);

            strWebPage = sr2.ReadToEnd();
            // Close and clean up the StreamReader
            sr2.Close();
        }
    }

    // dispose the first stream reader object
    sr.Close();

    return strWebPage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem with encoding, those funny strings like `&#xED;` are called [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

After conversion to correct encoding use [HttpUtility.HttpDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (from `System.Web` assembly) to convert html entities.