# convert the VNI-Windows into UTF-8?

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8, converters

I am using sample code in this topic: [Convert a string's character encoding from windows-1252 to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568033/convert-a-strings-character-encoding-from-windows-1252-to-utf-8) to convert vni-windows string to utf-8 string. However, it didn't work. Here's my code:

```
Encoding vns1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Encoding unicode = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] win1252 = vns1252.GetBytes(ems.Nguoi_goi);
byte[] utf8bytes = Encoding.Convert(vns1252, unicode, win1252);
string nguoigoi_utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8bytes);
Sheet1.Cells[i, 4] = nguoigoi_utf8;
```

My resuft: "Coâng ty TNHH Dòch Vuï Mua Saém T & T"

Any suggestions on how to convert the VNI-Windows into UTF-8?

Comment: What output would you expect?

Comment: And what input do you have...

Comment: Did you try this Encoding.Convert ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The VNI encoding isn't supported by Microsoft (and/or by .NET). There is no corresponding encoder/decoder. At a certain time Microsoft decided to support it, but there were legal problems with this (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNI and http://www.siao2.com/2012/09/18/10350350.aspx), so they abandoned the idea and created the Windows-1258 encoding (that is different from VNI).

Answer (score 0):

VNI encoding is different from Windows-1252.

Try as the first line instead this:

```
Encoding vns1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("VNI");
```

Comment: That encoding isn't supported (at least by that `VNI` name)

Comment: I think Microsoft doesn't support directly VNI, because it seems to be a proprietary standard... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNI and http://www.siao2.com/2012/09/18/10350350.aspx