# Save Word to UTF-8 Encoded HTML

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, ms-word, vsto

I am writing some C# VSTO code that reads a Microsoft Word document and saves it to Filtered HTML. When I perform this function on a generic Word document, the output of the html file uses a Windows Charset as witnessed here:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

If I open a document and go to File->Options->Advanced->Web Options, I can choose UTF8, and the resulting filtered html document output looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I want to write c# code that saves **any** Word document to filtered html with utf-8. After doing some research, I found some people saying the "SaveAs2" function does not work (even though Microsoft documents it as a feature). That means, this code does not work for me:

```
doc.SaveAs2("C:\\Temp\\Test.htm", MsWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML, Encoding: "65001");
```

(note: I tried putting the 65001 in quotes and without quotes.. neither throw errors, but neither works).

Next, I moved on to setting the web options for the document like this:

```
doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\\Temp\\Test.docx");
doc.WebOptions.Encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
doc.SaveAs2(destFile, MsWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML);
```

To the best of my knowledge the above code performs the same exact function as my manually opening a file, going to file->options..., setting to UTF-8 and saving the file to filtered html, yet the output still looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

Is there a way to force Microsoft Word to output a file to UTF-8 without having to manually configure the document first?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568033/convert-a-strings-character-encoding-from-windows-1252-to-utf-8

Comment: Using `doc.WebOptions.Encoding = msoEncodingUTF8` works for me. Are you sure you are checking the correct file?

Comment: @DirkVollmar, I have been trying this and it does not work. Then, I did a Doc.Fields.Update() before and it worked. Odd.

Answer (score 5):

At the time of this writing, it is unclear whether I have encountered a bug with my specific version of Microsoft Word (Word Online) or the VSTO template, but I will answer what made this work for me here.

If this code does not work:

```
doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\\Temp\\Test.docx");
doc.WebOptions.Encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
doc.SaveAs2("C:\\Temp\\Test.htm", MsWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML);
```

Then, change the code to refresh the document's fields, like this:

```
doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\\Temp\\Test.docx");

doc.Fields.Update(); // ** this is the new line of code.

doc.WebOptions.Encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
doc.SaveAs2("C:\\Temp\\Test.htm", MsWord.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks this saved my butt

Comment: Glad it helped. That was a really frustrating one!

Comment: lol and now my client wants to just use Word to PDF because they don't like the HTML conversion. Go figure lol...

Comment: At least you have another tool in your belt for the next one :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you have to add a reference:

In your project:

'MyProject' > Solution Explorer > References > Add Reference > COM > Microsoft Office 16.0 Object library

VS gives a very cryptic error that does not really help to find the lib.